# Как вызвать конструктор каждого элемента массива в операторе new?

Tags: java, конструктор

Мне нужно создать двумерный массив NxM из списков. В качестве списка я использую [Queue](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Queue.java.html). У этого класса есть конструктор по умолчанию, который мне нужно вызвать для каждого элемента матрицы. В идеале хотелось бы, чтобы работало вот так:

```
Queue<Character>[][] adjLetters = (Queue<Character>[][]) new Queue[N][M]();
```

Однако Java выдаёт ошибку: "Cannot cast from Queue to Queue<Character>[][]". Если убрать пустые круглые скобки в конце, то не вызывается конструктор каждой очереди. Если выделять память для каждой строки отдельно:

```
    Queue<Character>[][] adjLetters = (Queue<Character>[][]) new Queue[N][];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        adjLetters[i] = (Queue<Character>[]) new Queue[M];
    }
```

то опять же не вызывается конструктор. На ум приходит только написание двойного цикла с явным вызовом конструктора для каждого элемента. Можно ли как-нибудь попроще сделать?

Comment: Никак. Конструктор неявно вызываться не будет, сделайте явный двойной цикл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неверное понимание системы аллокаций объектов в Java:

Оператор `new MyClass[N]` не создает N объектов класса `MyClass`, а всего лишь создает массив из N ссылок на объекты класса `MyClass`

Именно поэтому никак не обойтись ручным созданием объектов в цикле (в вашем случае двойной цикл).